# Create and Run Dart Console Application Using VSCode?

Tags: dart

I can create Flutter new application using VSCode. Now I want to learn Dart programming language.

How can I create and run a Dart console application Using VS Code?

Comment: Here's a great video tutorial explaining [how to run dart console app in vscode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egrmMJkVrZM) hope it helps someone coming here in the future :)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There is an easy way to create and run a Dart console application:

1. Open VSCode
2. Press cmd + shift + p on Mac or ctrl + shift + p on windows.
3. Choose Dart: New project

[image]

4.Then you should select Console Application

[image]

5.After locating console application everything is ready for you

Well, how to run it? So easy!!!

Just go to terminal and type: "dart main.dart"

or copy the main.dart path then type: "dart (paste main file path)"

or press **ctrl + F5**

[image]

That's it. I hope you enjoy.

Comment: very helpful, can we do this automatically ?

Comment: Thanks! Please tell me what exactly you mean by automatically?

Comment: https://dart.dev/get-dart Get dart in case of dart SDK is not present

Answer (score 20):

Steps to run in VS Code:

- Open Visual Studio Code.
- Close whatever folder you have open.
- Make sure you have Dart Code Extension installed, or install it if you don't have it.

[image]

- Press Ctrl + Shift + P on Windows or  Cmd + Shift + P on Mac
- Select Dart: New Project

[image]

- Select Console Application

[image]

- Type in a name, example: hello_world
- Hit Enter
- Select a folder that already exists.
- Wait until it finishes

[image]

- main.dart file will show up.
- Hit Ctrl + F5 to run or Run, Run without debugging.
- In the Debug Console window, you will see the result.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Dart SDK installing with Flutter.
For MacOS Dart directory /Users/burak/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin

Add to PATH this bin directory and use dart with below.

```
dart --version
```

Run .dart file.

```
dart main.dart
```

Comment: favorite answer.

Comment: This is straight forward answer

Answer (score 5):

As of 2023 i found my solution. You required to install Flutter or Dart SDK in your device.

**Step 1:** Open VS Code and Press `cmd + shift + p` on Mac or `ctrl + shift + p` on windows.

**Step 2:** Type `dart` in there.

[image: type dart]

**Step 3:** Click on `Dart: New Project`

**Step 4:** Then Select `Console Application`

[image: Select Console Application]

**Step 5:** Then Select the folder where u want to create your project

**Step 6:** Then type your project name and hit enter.

[image: Project name]

**Step 7:** Now your project is created. Go inside bin folder and right click on the file inside bin and run the file.

[image: Bin folder]

Congrats you successfully created your dart console project. Now write your dart code inside bin folder. :)

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do it, you can install packages etc as well. instructions below..

**- Installing**

```
pub global activate stagehand
```

**- Add to .bash_profile**

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

**- Create and download packages**

mkdir fancy_project

```
cd fancy_project
stagehand console-full
pub get
```

Comment: I am wondering how to run it properly. `$ dart bin/main.dart` ??

Answer (score 3):

If you are not only flutter mobile developer, but web-developer too, you are probably using npm or yarn. If so you can use nodemon to run your dart code  automatically after any change

0. install brew and npm if you don't have it
1. install `$ npm install -g nodemon` (or yarn: `$ yarn global add nodemon` )
2. Create dart project.
3. Create `nodemon.json` file

   ```
    {
       "watch": [
        "lib/" // or any other place where you hold the dart files
      ],
      "execMap": {
         "dart": "dart"
       },
      "ext": "dart"
    }
   ```
4. Run you code: `$ nodemon ./lib/main.dart`

p.s. Code in the .dart file should have main function:

```
void main() {
  print('hello world');
}
```

If you are using VsCode, just save code by `CMD + S` and nodemon demon will run updated code,

Answer (score 1):

If you already have flutter (windows) installed , then find where you installed flutter. Once you are in flutter folder then go through

flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin .

I have installed flutter on C:\src folder so my path is

C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin  .

Now copy this full path and set it as environment variable. 
If you can't set environment variable then open search bar and type "env"  . Click the result click environment variable and add that path in( Path variable).

In VScode Ctrl+Shift+`  this will open a new terminal . Right click on your dart code and copy path.

In terminal just type this line without bracket and press enter
 [dart "paste path"]

Answer (score 1):

**Straight Forward Answer**

1. Install Flutter SDK ( this contains dart SDK by default )
2. Add dart to you environment path

Now create a dart file and run it with the dart command, for example create sunday.dart file and put the following content inside.

```dart
void main(){
  print("HAVE A NICE DAY")
}
```

run the dart code with the following code
`dart sunday.dart`   the output will be

`HAVE A NICE DAY`

Answer (score 0):

If you have already run flutter application on VSCode, then you should be able to run dart console applications. However, please check the following:

1. Dart SDK is already installed on your system.
2. Check if the Dart 2.20 Extension (Current Version) is already installed on the VSCode. If not, please install the same on your VSCode, and restart VSCode.
3. Create Dart console application and save with `.dart` extension (say `Hello.dart`), in a suitable location.
4. From the top menu bar of VSCode, open a terminal. From the
   terminal inside of the VSCode, change to directory where you have saved
   the dart program.
5. Run the dart console program with the command:

   ```
   dart [hello.dart]
   ```

Console program results are shown in the terminal. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this JSON code in your `setting.json` in the `.vscode` folder .

```
"dart.sdkPath": "[DART_SDK_PATH]"
```

For example in my Windows OS :

```
"dart.sdkPath": "F:\\dev\\sdk\\dart-sdk"
```

And My All Setting in `setting.json` :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Dart",
            "program": "bin/main.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ] ,

    "dart.sdkPath": "F:\\dev\\sdk\\dart-sdk"  
}
```

Notice the This Image :

[image: Dart Setup in vscode]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the dcli package. It is an sdk for building console apps in dart.

To create a sample dart console app that demonstrates a number of best practices run

```
dcli create --template=full myproject
```

Answer (score 0):

**[image: To run dart hello world from VSCODE]**

boom that's it. it will print value in console.