# Run a .dart file for experimenting. (VS Code)

Tags: dart

I'm writing an app using VS Code on Windows, but I like testing small peices of dart code before using it in the app to ensure everything is working as I expected. Here's a simple example:

```
lib/
    main.dart
    dart_experiments.dart
```

And in `dart_experiments.dart`:

```
void main() {
    print('Hello world.');
}
```

How can I just run this file by itself and see the results in the console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create and Run Dart Console Application Using VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822524/create-and-run-dart-console-application-using-vscode)

Comment: @Saeed I switched to vim for dart development, so I'm unfortunately not sure whether any of these answers work.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the Dart SDK installed you can run it using

```
dart lib/main.dart
```

From VSCode this probably only works well on a plain Dart project (not a Flutter project)

In Flutter I'd suggest to put the files in `test/...` and then run it from there.

Tests are run without an emulator or device by default from the IDE
and from the command line you can use

```
flutter test test/main.dart
```

Comment: The issue was that Flutter had not added `dart-sdk/bin` to the environment variables, so `dart my_file.dart` was not working. As for running the tests via Flutter, it took a full 10 seconds to print "Hello world". It's faster to just run it via `dart tests/dart_experiments.dart`. If you're curious, the `flutter test` output looked like this: `00:10 +0: loading ...\dart_experiments.dart
Hello world.
No tests ran.`

Answer (score 3):

After installing the Dart plugin (**dart-code.dart-code**) , the Interactive mode provides the option to RUN/DEBUG dart code from the file itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Edit launch.json to Specify An Alternative Profile That Only Runs Current File

1. Edit `.vscode/launch.json` to add a launch profile for a specific file.

   Here's an example, the first one being the primary profile to run the main.dart file, and the second one to specify a launch in test mode that runs only the current file being edited :

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "launch-chrome",
      "cwd": "myproject",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "args": [
        "--web-port", "4395", "-dchrome"
      ],
      "program": "lib/main.dart"

    },  {  
     "name": "launch-scrap",
     "cwd": "myproject",
     "request": "launch",
     "type": "dart",
     "program": "${file}", //<--- Executed Current File Only
     "args": ["test"], //<--- Execute only in test mode, no device
   }
  ]
}
```

2. The first profile will launch by default when `F5` is pressed.
3. Press `CTRL-SHIFT-p` and start typing `DEBUG: Select and Start Debugging` and select it when it appears. You will then be given a choice to run the second profile.
4. Or type `CTRL-SHIFT-D` and pick the second launch profile to debug your file.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed these correctly, then you can run the program by Ctrl + F5.

1 - dart SDK
2 - vscode
3 - dart extension in vscode