# How to run an individual dart file in Flutter without having to build the UI in vscode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I know that in Android Studio you could run a dart file that you put out of the lib folder individually much like dartpad. I'm wondering how you could do the same in VSCode. I haven't found a way to do it without it running and building the whole UI.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822524/create-and-run-dart-console-application-using-vscode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run a dart file from the command line like this.

`$ dart path_to_your_file/your_file_with_main.dart`

This will execute the main() function of the file.

Comment: This is the right answer but gets awkward when you're using a library that assumes flutter is running (imports break when running directly via dart)

Answer (score 0):

After creating a flutter project to **run individually dart file in Flutter**

you have to add **main function** like below code with you desire class name

**void main() { runApp(newfile()); }**

or

**void main() => runApp(newfile());**

then go to project bar of android studio right click on the selected file you **will see Run'newfile.dart'** then you will also see in the toolbar, select your app from the run configurations drop-down menu
like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select File and Edit Configuration
2. Add Run External Tools
3. Add `dart` in Program & Working dir `$ProjectFileDir$`

[image: Edit Config]
[image: Run External Tools]
[image: Change tool settings]