# Unable to run a dart program inside VS code

Tags: bash, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am new to Dart/flutter. I have installed **flutter SDK** and **VS Code** on **windows 10** machine, updated the system path, run flutter doctor, which shows that flutter is indeed installed ([flutter doctor output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYssJ.png)). I read that installing flutter is enough, and I don't have to install Dart SDK too, as it comes build in with flutter (please correct me if I am wrong).

I wrote a very short Dart code for testing, but I couldn't run it from VS Code terminal ([run in terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVgqF.png)), as it returns the following error: "bash: dart: command not found".

But when I debug the code in VS Code, it returns the expected output ([debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsjk8.png)).

Can someone please explain to me if I am doing something wrong, or if I am missing something? Why can't I run the program from the bash terminal?

Thanks

Comment: It seem to be path to the dart binary related.  Your vscode project probably contain .vscode/launch.json that configure to where the path to dart binary is located.  So if you want to run it from a terminal, add the path to dart binary to your environment variable and restart your terminal session.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I only added flutter sdk to the path environment, while I should have added dart sdk (which is located within flutter directory) to the path as well; after doing so, everything works.

Comment: Try F5 or Run -> Start Debugging which is considered the correct way to launch a Dart or Flutter project in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

You should enter the full path directory instead of file name. For doing so right click on the dart file then choose `Copy Path`.

[image]

Then run following code on terminal:

```
dart (paste main file path)
```

[image]

For more information about creating and running Dart console application using VSCode please check out [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822524/create-and-run-dart-console-application-using-vscode/59758574#59758574) answer.