# How to run Dart code in Visual Studio Code terminal?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Why can't I run *dart main.dart* on the cmd but not on the terminal of Visual Studio Code? I can't even change the directory.

Output of terminal here:
[image: output of terminal here]

Comment: can you share the terminal image

Comment: Yes this is the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrkFA.png

Comment: Ur space inside ```dart practice\bin``` needs to be escaped, try changing it to ```dart/ practice\bin```

Comment: Can you send flutter plugin path image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create and Run Dart Console Application Using VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822524/create-and-run-dart-console-application-using-vscode)

Answer (score 0):

In the first command you typed `cd \bin` which is trying to find a `bin` folder from your root. You should've just used `cd bin` (though probably instead running `dart bin/main.dart` from the root is better).

In the second command, there is a space in the path so you need to put quotes around the whole path.

That said, you may find it better to run your app using the Run menu in VS Code (eg. pressing F5), as you'll get full debugger support that way.